# google charts: Object has no method 'getTime'

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I'm using google charts (line chart) with a datetime on the xAxis and a number on the yAxis.
I activated horizontal zoom but every time I try to zoom in I get the following exception:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object 1387717025773 has no method 'getTime' format+de,default+de,ui+de,corechart+de.I.js:826
```

I reproduced the problem in the google code playground with the following sample code:

```
function drawVisualization() {
  // Create and populate the data table.
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['time', 'test'],
    [new Date(1387717025701),   1],
    [new Date(1387717025801),   2],
    [new Date(1387717025901),   4],
    [new Date(1387717026001),   8],
  ]);

  // Create and draw the visualization.
  new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
    draw(data, {curveType: "function",
                width: 500, height: 400,
                vAxis: {maxValue: 10}, title: 'test',
                //hAxis: {maxValue: 10},
                hAxis: {format: "HH:MM:ss"},
                explorer: { actions: ['dragToZoom', 'rightClickToReset'], axis: 'horizontal'} 
               });
}
```

Just go to https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#line_chart paste the above code and try to zoom in by dragging. In the browsers (I'm using chrome) console the error should appear.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is already reported and accepted issue at Google. See issue 1395 [Bug: "explorer" option throws an error when panning/zooming on a "date" type axis](https://code.google.com/p/google-visualization-api-issues/issues/detail?id=1395).

You can get little better behaviour if you chose vertical axis instead of horizontal. `dragToZoom` works but when you use right click to reset chart you get the same error.